# Can a theme set faces normally provided by another package?

Tags: themes, customize

I want to produce a custom theme. I understand how to set built-in faces, like `font-lock-nnn` ones, modeline, etc.

I wonder if I can provide colors for faces that are defined by other packages, e.g. by magit, or by js2. (Inheritance helps but does not suffice.)

I suppose that a theme file can just define a function, and I could invoke it depending on presence of certain faces / variables some time later, but it looks like a hack, and won't work with normal customizations done via `customize-group`.

Comment: Did you check existing themes for examples? Eg https://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven-theme/blob/master/leuven-theme.el#L627

Comment: @muffinmad: Thanks, this is helpful!

Comment: Yes, in particular, several themes have colors for `rainbow-delimiters`.